# Button Detector Python

Tags: python, keyboard

How would you write code to detect if the left button is pressed and, for instance, if there is a time frame of around 0.50 seconds for pressing the "Alt" key twice?

```
import keyboard
import time

left_trigger = False
alt_trigger = False
alt_trigger2 = False

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('left'):
        if not left_trigger:
           print('Left is pressed')
           left_trigger = True
        
    elif left_trigger and keyboard.is_pressed('alt') :
        if not alt_trigger:
            alt_trigger = True
            print('Alt is pressed')
            start_time = time.time()

    elif alt_trigger and time.time() - start_time < 0.5 :
        if not alt_trigger2:
            alt_trigger2 = True
            print('Alt is pressed again within 0.5 seconds')

else:
    left_trigger = False
    alt_trigger = False
    alt_trigger2 = False
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want to detect if the alt button is pressed within 0.5 seconds of the left button is pressed? If so, what you want your program to do in that case?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the start time when the button is pressed and then get the difference of current time when it is pressed again to see the elapsed time. Then you can check to see if it is > 0.5 seconds.

Something like this:

```
import keyboard
import time

left_trigger = False
alt_trigger = False
alt_trigger2 = False

last_pressed = time.time()

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('left'):
        if not left_trigger:
           print('Left is pressed')
           left_trigger = True
        
    elif left_trigger and keyboard.is_pressed('alt') :
        if time.time() - last_pressed < 0.5:
            print('Alt is pressed again within 0.5 seconds')
            
        last_pressed = time.time()
        if not alt_trigger:
            alt_trigger = True
            print('Alt is pressed')


else:
    left_trigger = False
    alt_trigger = False
    alt_trigger2 = False
```

But you may want to check when the key is released to tell when a new press actually happens.